# 3 Drop downs list to populate a search bar

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a drop down list which populates a search bar from 3 different drop down lists..  I am trying to have it update the search bar after each selection and keep the prior selections,  so it would read 175/55/17 in the search bar. Yes I am a complete noob, please help!  Here's what I have so far:

Here's my updated code, still doesn't populate the search field on the site or on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_i

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script language= "javascript" stype="text/javascript" type:"text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { $('select').change(function () { 
$('#_shop_itemsearch_query').val($('#Width').val() + '/' + $('#height').val() + '/' +
$('#size').val()); }); }); </script> 
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="_shop_itemsearch_query" id="_shop_itemsearch_query" class="v2_shop_form_input"> 

<form action=""> <select name="Width" id="width"> 
<option value="175"selected>175</option> 
<option value="185">185</option> 
<option value="195">195</option> 
<option value="205">205</option> 
<option value="215">215</option> 
<option value="225">225</option> 
<option value="235">235</option> 
<option value="245">245</option> 
<option value="255">255</option> 
<option value="265">265</option> 
<option value="275">275</option> 
<option value="285">285</option> 
<option value="295">295</option> 
<option value="305">305</option> 
<option value="315">315</option> 
<option value="325">325</option> 
<option value="335">335</option> 
<option value="345">345</option> 
</select> 
<form action=""> 
<select name="Height" id="height"> 
<option value="20"selected>20</option> 
<option value="25">25</option> 
<option value="30">30</option> 
<option value="35">35</option> 
<option value="40">40</option> 
<option value="45">45</option> 
<option value="50">50</option> 
<option value="55">55</option> 
<option value="60">60</option> 
<option value="65">65</option> 
<option value="70">70</option> 
<option value="75">75</option> 
<option value="80">80</option> 
<option value="85">85</option> 
</select> 
<form action=""> 
<select name="Size" id="size"> 
<option value="15"selected>15</option> 
<option value="16">16</option> 
<option value="17">17</option> 
<option value="18">18</option> 
<option value="19">19</option> 
<option value="20">20</option> 
<option value="21">21</option> 
<option value="22">22</option> 
<option value="24">24</option> 
<option value="25">25</option> 
</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what seems to be tripping you up?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Have you tried using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=autocomplete&aq=0&oq=autocmplete&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3.2803j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('#_shop_itemsearch_query').val($('#Width').val() + '/' + $('#height').val() + '/' + $('#size').val());
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WMKcn/1)**

Comment: these both work in the jsFiddle, but not on the page. am I doing something wrong?sorry for the noobness
<Script type="text/javascript">$('select').change(function () {
    $('#_shop_itemsearch_query').val($('#Width').val() + '/' + $('#height').val() + '/' + $('#size').val());
});
</script>

Comment: Unless I can see the actual page or full code where it's not working I can't do much more since my answer and fiddle work. You can try and debug your code by looking for errors in the console.

Comment: with the exception of what's in <Script type="text/javascrpit"> (changed mine to what you have) </script>, the code is all the same, using [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro) as a html test bed  Sorry for all the questions, 2nd day in jquery

Comment: I updated my answer to include a snippet of code you may have been leaving out that that jsFiddle includes automatically. Give that a shot in the head of your page.

Comment: I've updated the code and re-posted it in my question, but it's still not working on the page or the checker.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var str = "";

    $('select').each(function(index){
        str += $(this).val();
        if(index != $('select').length - 1)str += '/';
    })

    $('#_shop_itemsearch_query').val(str)
})
```

Not tested but should work.

Comment: these both work in the jsFiddle, but not on the page.  am I doing something wrong?

    <Script type="text/javascript">

$('select').change(function(){
    var str = "";

    $('select').each(function(index){
        str += $(this).val();
        if(index != $('select').length - 1)str += '/';
    })

    $('#_shop_itemsearch_query').val(str)
    })
    </script>

Comment: Is it called at the and of the document (after the DOM load)? If not, put it at the end OR and `$(document).ready(function(){The code})`

Comment: If that's not the problem, we will need the full HTML

Comment: Also, just to be sure, did you linked the jQuery librairy? Seems like you are using pure JS in your question.

Comment: I've updated the code, but still can;t get it working, must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You are not linking jQuery to your document. Insert before the first `<script>` tag this line : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`